# Show different sidebar items or hide some components based on user-role after login (VUEJS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, user-management

How can I go about populating a sidebar with appropriate menu items based on user role?. i need to show and hide some components based on user or admin login  in vuejs.

Comment: you can use v-if for conditional rendering. here the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

Comment: is there any demo link bro?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be in the `created` life-cycle function, get the `user_role`, then have a `computed` property compute what should be shown in the sidebar. This way you can change the users and get new sidebars each time the component is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the user role and add a 'permission' field in menu.

Here is an example:

```
{
  id: "dashboard",
  icon: "iconsminds-monitor-analytics",
  label: "menu.dashboard",
  to: "/app/dashboard",
  permission: ["ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_TECHNICIAN", "ROLE_DOCTOR"],
},
```

Comment: can i have reference for this ? when and how permission can be checked?